# How to test missing optional perl modules via the command line perl call

Tags: perl

I have a test suite with hundreds of tests for a perl module I've yet to release which is a command line interface.  Since it is a command line interface, the tests (until possibly now) are all written to drop code into a template and then call the template script using a system call.

I recently added an optional dependency on a 3rd party module that's not a part of core perl.  I know my module works whether that module is installed or not because I have a computer with it installed and one without and the module works without error in each case.  However, I'd like to be able to write a test to confirm that my module will work when the 3rd party module is absent - and I'd like that test to work even if the 3rd party module *is* installed, but behave as if it wasn't.

Ideally, I could use the structure I've put in place for testing which makes a system call to a template script.  I know I could write a separate test script that manipulates @INC in the BEGIN block, imports the particular methods that use the module, and call them like a unit test.  But I would like to know if there's a way I can use the test structure I've already got all my other tests using, which is to make a system call.

So is there a way to exclude a module from being imported via a perl command line option?  I've tried -M-Module, but the code `use Module` still imports the module.

Incidentally, my module uses the 3rd party module inside an eval, which is how I made it optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote [Test::Without::Module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Without::Module) for this exact case. It works by modifying `@INC` to prevent loading of modules that you name. For testing, you could either run the test from the command line:

```
perl -MTest::Without::Module=Some::Module -w -Iblib/lib t/SomeModule.t
```

Or allow/disallow loading the module from within your test suite:

```
use Test::Without::Module qw( My::Module );

# Now, loading of My::Module fails :
eval { require My::Module; };
warn $@ if $@;

# Now it works again
eval q{ no Test::Without::Module qw( My::Module ) };
eval { require My::Module; };
print "Found My::Module" unless $@;
```

Comment: Ah, you're the one with the perlmonks post. Great. I admit I was too impatient to read the whole thing. But I'm glad I posted because your response really boiled it down. I'll definitely try it out.

Comment: So I just realized I have to solve another issue before I can tell whether this test will work. For the module Term::ReadKey, I don’t eval the use of the module unless I detect I have a connection to a tty. So I have to figure out how to make the script think it’s open to a tty. And I need to make sure that the width of that tty is not my default of 80... 

Comment: ... or trigger that by setting some environment variable or command line switch.#

Comment: Hmmm. Even if I can trigger the eval, I can’t confirm that the test was successful unless I can test the inverse case. I need a positive test that the 3rd party module loaded and sets the term width != 80 and a negative test where the module doesn’t load and I get the default width of 80. I guess that’s not your problem though. I will select this answer once I get it figured out and everything works.

Comment: I would set up different test files for those test cases, and make sure that the module can load or does not, respectively. You can usually fake the terminal width by setting `$ENV{COLS}`.

Comment: I'm almost there! I can make my system calls output to a tty by doing `perl mytest.pl > /dev/tty000`, but I can't figure out how to get the output back so I can see if the width is correct.  I tried `perl mytest.pl > /dev/tty000;cat /dev/tty000` but that hangs (presumably waiting for input).  Does anyone know how to flush a tty's buffer without it waiting for more input?

Comment: I had to use a call to `script` so that I could redirect to a tty *and* retrieve the output from a temp file I gave to `script`.

Comment: Although, I just confirmed that the `script` command on my mac is not compatible on linux... Going to have to figure that one out...